# How to add floating numbers in java

Tags: java, precision, floating-accuracy

Am I missing something basic in Java Math calculations for float numbers ? I can use Math function round(), However I want accurate value 6.4 as the input given is simple and doesn't have many values after the decimal point.

```
System.out.println(1.8f+1.0f+1.9f+1.7f); // Expected 6.4 but actual is 6.3999999999999995 how ?
```

Comment: the short answer being "no, 6.4 is absolutely not expected" because IEEE floating point numbers are lossy approximations for decimal numbers. Just because you write some number, doesn't mean the floating point value will actually _be_ that number.

Comment: What is the reason you use floating points here?

Comment: @aydinugur - probably no reason.  It is an example.  Besides, it doesn't make any difference if the OP uses `float` or `double`.  The same sort of thing occurs with all primitive binary floating point types.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply, So we need to use BigDecimal type to sum the floating decimals in Java ?